# Run each theory in different test class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, static, xunit

Assume I have a test class with a theory method that runs with two inputs, "irrelevant" and "irrelevant2". The test first checks if a static class "IsInitialized", if it does, the test fails.

Then, the test initializes the static class by calling "Initialize".

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("irrelevant")]
[InlineData("irrelevant2")]
public void Test(string param)
{
    if (MyStaticClass.IsInitialized()) { throw new Exception(); }
    MyStaticClass.Initialize();
}

public static class MyStaticClass
{
    private static bool Initialized = false;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Initialized = true;
    }

    public static bool IsInitialized()
    {
        return Initialized;
    }
}
```

What I expect is that both tests will pass, as the static class is only initialized after calling "Initialize". However, the result is that the first test pass and the second fails, because the static class remains in memory. I'd expect the static class state to revert to its initial. I can understand why this is happening, because of using a static. However, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to configure the test to dispose the memory of the static class as if I would run a new test case.

This would also happen if I had two "Fact"s with the same code in them. When running each fact separately, both tests would pass. When running the test class, one would pass (the first) and the second would fail.

Comment: That's the reason why your tests should be independent from side effects. Initialize everything needed for your SUT within the test method and don't rely on static values within your test class. Ensure all tests can be run in any order and / or in parallel to ensure your test results are stable. If you can't ensure this, you have a design flaw that must be fixed.

Comment: What if I test the static class itself? Side effects are irrelevant in this case as this is the test case. I have updated the question with a new example.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is expected behavior. If you set the value of static field `Initialized` to "true" in one test, when you run the next test it's going to be "true".

There are a few ways to look at this:

- If all you're testing is that setting a field's value actually works, just don't test that. It's not so much a behavior of your code as a feature of the language. Do we need to write tests to verify that setting a property really sets it? Likely not.
- If you have to test it, don't write tests that must fail if the language works correctly. Write a test that verifies that the value is whatever you set it to. A test that verifies what the value *is not* isn't very useful.
- Consider not using a `static` class and property. The reasons for using a static vs. an instance class are specific to whatever you're coding. I don't know your reasons. But often the challenges we encounter when testing reflect the problems we'll have when using the code "for real."
- You asked if you could "dispose" it from memory. You can't do that, or at least the process for doing it is so complicated that you shouldn't do it. You could add a method to your static class that "resets" the value. But that's a little messy. If we have to add methods to static classes just so we can test them then maybe we should consider not using a static class.

Comment: Well this is obviously not the full code. What I am testing is that the Initialize method initializes the class properties, and that it can only be initialized once (in the real code, initializing at the second call will throw). The usage of a static class at this context is mandatory, I can't use an instance class instead.
What it means is that if I have two test scenarios for initialization (this is where the theory comes from), I can only test one scenario, as the first one will leave the static class in a different state.

Comment: Unfortunately that's going to be difficult. It's a common problem with static classes in general, but especially when they have "Initialize" methods that are only supposed to be called once. It's not just this class that will be untestable. It may be difficult to write tests that depend on this code. Can you make an instance class but ensure that there will only be one instance? That's the ideal solution. If you're using `IServiceCollection`, it's `services.AddSingleton<Whatever>(new Whatever());` or something similar.

Comment: It's impossible to use instance class and containers in specific, as this static class is being used before the container build phase.

Comment: If we look at this objectively, I don't see a design problem with using a static class that exposes an initialization method. The problem comes from the test framework, that doesn't enable an option to run each test instance in a new test class instance, and not share static contexts. The purpose of this thread was to see if there was a way to run each test instance in a new execution, same as if I were to split this tests to two different test classes.

Comment: I looked into executing these tests in another application domain but you can't even do that. I thought it would work as a last resort but it doesn't. If you must test this then a "reset" method is all I can think of. I just don't like the idea of having it exposed to the rest of my code. You could do something really weird like return a Guid from the `Initialize` method, store it, and require `Reset` to pass it back. That way in production code if it goes out of scope there's no way to retrieve it so it won't be called. But ..ugh.

Comment: Seems like a wrong thing to do - changing the production logic just because the test framework has such limitations. I though about using a singleton pattern, but it still uses a static values, so its irrelevant. Can you think of any other way to resolve this?

Comment: If the problem is that you must test the logic in different scenarios, can you create an instance class and create an instance of it in the static class, and write tests for the instance class? If the requirement is that you must be able to write tests for the static code itself, there's just no good way to do it. It's not the test framework - it's .NET.

Comment: Creating an instance class from static class is a sort of factorizing instance classes. This does not help my in my flow, I must use a static class and therefore I'd like to test the static class.